# IText7--How to get the separation color of a PDF file and draw a line with this color

Tags: .net-core, itext7

[The pdf file](https://1drv.ms/b/s!AqxJcIfHZ18UjQ-cUY0a9CwOtjlb?e=fV3uyE)

```
var inputPath = @"E:\Separation.pdf";
var outputPath = @"E:\Separation_out.pdf";
using (PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(inputPath), new PdfWriter(outputPath)))
    {
       PdfDictionary resources = pdfDocument.GetFirstPage().GetPdfObject().GetAsDictionary(PdfName.Resources);
       PdfDictionary colorSpaces = resources.GetAsDictionary(PdfName.ColorSpace);
       foreach (PdfName key in colorSpaces.KeySet())
         {
           PdfObject colorSpace = colorSpaces.Get(key);
           //How to
         }
    }
```

I only got the initial information about it, but couldn't really get it and use it. Can anyone help me? Thank you so much.